# Can Angular search active directory (not Azure) using a managed service account

Tags: angular, active-directory

What I'm building:
I'm building a self service type kiosk, for walk up IT support.

Component I'm currently working on:
Active directory search with ID card number as filter (user swipes card) and pulls back name and username

Issue:
The company I'm working for has a preference for using managed service accounts, I've so far been unable to find anything online on if I can/cannot use a managed service account with Angular vs the lesser preferred of using a service account by username/password

Versions:
Node: 10.16.3
NPM: 6.9.0

Does anyone have any advice/links on information or tutorials on how to use managed service accounts with Angular if it is possible?

Appreciate any advice/tips

Comment: Angular is just client side, wouldn't it be easier if your server side handle that and return a response?

Answer (score 0):

Client side code (run in the browser) will not be able to communicate with AD directly. The browser will simply not allow it.

Your server-side code will have to make the communication to AD, and your client side code can talk to your server.

If you're using NodeJS on the server, there is a package called [`activedirectory2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2) for communicating with AD. Give it a try.